# Can I use the word "engage" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

> News media plays a significant role in our everyday lives, and we need to actively **engage** with it. If we don’t,

can I use the word "engage" here?

Comment: It seems like your title is incomplete.

Comment: could you tell us what you mean exactly by "engage" ?

Comment: This comment has been edited in a way that may not reflect the OP's intent. "News media" is currently used in both a plural and singular sense. The edit makes the usage consistent between the clauses, but that does not mean it reflects what the OP was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

This is a hard question to answer. I doubt that you mean "news media" but suspect that you really mean the "news."

Most people do not "engage" with the news media at all. How often do you chat with the publisher of the New York Times? Does Lester Holt listen to your criticisms of his take on the news? Few of us have anything but the barest influence over the people and organizations that gather and present the news.

If you mean "news" rather than "news media," then I would not use the word "engage" with its implications of serious dialogue. You may talk to your television, but it does not respond to your comments. I know that it is currently fashionable among some to use "engage" to mean "think critically," but it would be better to say precisely what you mean.

Now this answer may be completely off base if I have misinterpreted what you are trying to convey, but if I am correct then I would write something like

> The news has a major effect on our everyday lives, and thus we need/ought to assess/scrutinize/analyze it with great care. If we don't, ...

To summarize, few of us have any chance to "engage" with the news media of any kind. In one sense, one can "engage" with the news itself, but it is a vague sense. Thus, it would be better to clarify what you really mean.